# Clone lighting effects not working in scratch.mit.edu

Tags: clone, lighting, mit-scratch

I am working on making lighting effects in scratch. However, my code won't completely light the screen and will only light a small area of the stage. The rest of my systems seem to be working, however, including the shadows. Here's my code:

[image: Here's my code:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clone limit is preventing it from working: stamping and deleting clones will make it work.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably set size to 200 or the largest it can be if the size is really small